# Can I change my seat on a Eurostar booking booked through DB?

Tags: trains, germany, eurostar

I have a Fahrkarte SPARPREIS EUROPA from London St. Pancras to Frankfurt with change in Brux-Mi., bought through a travel agent from DB Vertrieb GmbH.  The ticket is attached to a Kundenbeleg that describes the seat number and reservation, but the ticket itself does not give this information, and the Kundenbeleg is in German.  According to [Mark Smith posting on Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g187275-i116-k7803314-Bahn_de_Eurostar_tickets_not_showing_on_Eurostar_site-Germany.html), this is not a problem and the ticket will be accepted.  No problem there.  However, normally I change my seat to choose a seat I prefer.  Is this possible when the Eurostar ticket was issues by DB?

Comment: I have never tried this so just a comment. In my experience asking Eurostar about anything outside Eurostar (like DB or travel onwards to any Belgian station) draws a complete blank but you could try via their web page Contact us options and hope I was just unlucky. You did pick up from Mark Smith that you need to go to the staffed check-in in the middle of the row of auto ones presumably?

Comment: @mdewey Yes, I've travelled once before with such a ticket but that was before I got in the habit of always changing my seat to my favourite seat before travel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, my understanding is that the answer is no.

From https://help.loco2.com/article/306-seating-preferences-and-choosing-a-seat

> Changing Eurostar seats after booking
>
> The only rail operator who permits a seat change after booking is
>   Eurostar.

While there is nothing to lose by contacting Eurostar directly, Loco2 sell both types of ticket and I would expect their analysis to be correct.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Mark Perryman's answer: as far as I know, this is impossible online. However, I have succeeded in getting my seat changed when checking in at the counter with my DB ticket. Of course the choice will be much more limited at this stage, and it may be completely impossible if the train's fully booked. But it's worth trying, especially if you're after some general category (‘window’, ‘near a door’, ‘near the buffet’, etc.) rather than one exact seat. In my case it was ‘My companion and I booked separately, but is there any way you could seat us together?’.

Comment: I usually look for *Forward-facing, farthest ahead carriage in my class category, real window seat, European power outlet*, but as I may even fail this 3 weeks in advance I very much doubt they'll be able to do this at the checkin counter!